# Test Matrix for pre-computed kernel in libsvm (scikit learn)

Tags: testing, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I am using Weisfeiler-Lehman Graph Kernels [from here](https://github.com/mahito-sugiyama/graph-kernels/) to get the precomputed kernel for the Scikit learn SVM [see description](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#using-the-gram-matrix).

At test time, what should be the format of my data? I'm really confused about that. [See dimension requirements.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict)

Thanks very much.

Comment: Could you please extract some of the important bits from those links into the question so it's a bit easier to get the big picture? Thanks

Comment: @MattFletcher, the main part is, since the `predict(X)` function of scikit-learn SVM needs an `X is [n_samples_test, n_samples_train]` matrix, what does this mean intuitively?